# Akka warning about "Too many HashedWheelTimer instances"

Tags: scala, akka

I'm getting the following warning when my Akka 1.2-based application tries to work with more than 500 or so grid nodes:

```
Jan 05, 2012 1:36:43 PM org.jboss.netty.util.internal.SharedResourceMisuseDetector
WARNING: You are creating too many HashedWheelTimer instances.  
HashedWheelTimer is a shared resource that must be reused across the application, so that only a few instances are created.
```

I'm going to dig more deeply into the Akka code to find out where the HashedWheelTimer is being used and what I should do to avoid too many of those being created. While I'm doing that, I thought I'd post the warning here in case one of the experts may be able to give me a pointer or two that may narrow and speed up my search, please?

Using Akka 1.3-RC6, I'm getting the following exception:

```
Jan 12, 2012 1:24:38 PM org.jboss.netty.util.HashedWheelTimer
WARNING: An exception was thrown by TimerTask.
org.jboss.netty.channel.ChannelException: Failed to open a socket.
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioClientSocketChannel.newSocket(NioClientSocketChannel.java:49)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioClientSocketChannel.<init>(NioClientSocketChannel.java:83)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioClientSocketChannelFactory.newChannel(NioClientSocketChannelFactory.java:139)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioClientSocketChannelFactory.newChannel(NioClientSocketChannelFactory.java:86)
    at org.jboss.netty.bootstrap.ClientBootstrap.connect(ClientBootstrap.java:218)
    at org.jboss.netty.bootstrap.ClientBootstrap.connect(ClientBootstrap.java:188)
    at akka.remote.netty.ActiveRemoteClient.connect(NettyRemoteSupport.scala:470)
    at akka.remote.netty.ActiveRemoteClientHandler$$anonfun$channelClosed$1$$anon$4.run(NettyRemoteSupport.scala:599)
    at org.jboss.netty.util.HashedWheelTimer$HashedWheelTimeout.expire(HashedWheelTimer.java:519)
    at org.jboss.netty.util.HashedWheelTimer$Worker.notifyExpiredTimeouts(HashedWheelTimer.java:440)
    at org.jboss.netty.util.HashedWheelTimer$Worker.run(HashedWheelTimer.java:379)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Too many open files
    at sun.nio.ch.Net.socket0(Native Method)
    at sun.nio.ch.Net.socket(Net.java:323)
    at sun.nio.ch.Net.socket(Net.java:316)
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.<init>(SocketChannelImpl.java:101)
    at sun.nio.ch.SelectorProviderImpl.openSocketChannel(SelectorProviderImpl.java:60)
    at java.nio.channels.SocketChannel.open(SocketChannel.java:142)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioClientSocketChannel.newSocket(NioClientSocketChannel.java:47)
    ... 11 more
```

Comment: Thanks Dan, you beat me to the edit...

Comment: My crystal ball is unable to determine what version of Akka you're running.

Comment: My apologies; I've edited the post to reflect that I'm using Akka 1.2.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Has been fixed in Akka 2.0-M1, I've now backported the fix to 1.3 and it will be in the next RC.

Comment: Will try out 1.3 and let you know if that fixes the issue. Thanks Viktor; have a good weekend.

Comment: I think I nailed the issue and backported the fix. It will be in the next RC of 1.3

Comment: Beautiful; thanks Viktor! I'll download it and test it out as soon as it is released and let you know if that solves the issue on my end... Thanks! :-)

Comment: BTW, my preliminary understanding is that the HashedWheelTimer is being used to keep netty connections alive. If more than about 800 or so netty connections are simultaneously open, the warning is generated and the connections stop working properly (in the 1.2 version). Is this roughly correct? Thanks for any insights.

Comment: No, it creates a HWT for each outbound connection, which for 800 connections is quite a few, my fix is to only use 1 HWT no matter how many outbound connections

Comment: Ah I see.... thanks for the insights Viktor. Thanks very much for back-porting this to v1.3. Will test 1.3 RC6 ASAP and update here.

Comment: Hi Viktor, sorry for the delay. I'm not getting that warning anymore, but a ChannelException is being thrown and after that our server is failing to make progress. I am adding the exception stack-trace to my question body above.

Comment: I think I know what it is, let me suggest a fix tomorrow

Comment: CAn you build the current HEAD of the "release-1.3"-branch of Akka and see if that improves things or not? I have more ammo but would like to see if that fixes your problem before going further.

Comment: in the middle of another test right now; will try this first thing tomorrow and let you know.... thanks Viktor!

Comment: Great, thanks. If "release-1.3" doesn't solve it, try the "release-1.3-remotefix-√"-branch, and tell me what worked :-)

Comment: I downloaded the release-1.3 zip file from https://github.com/jboner/akka/zipball/release-1.3. Not sure if I'm missing the build instructions somehow; is the correct build approach to run the project/build/AkkaProject.scala (which seems to contain maven repository info, dependencies, etc). I also saw the scripts in project/scripts but there the "build-release" script referred to in ("release") seems to be missing. Thanks for any hints about how to build the codebase.

Comment: But since we're on a bit of a tight schedule here, send me an e-mail to viktor dot klang at typesafe dot com and I can send you the artifacts you need. (give me a list of your akka dependencies)

Comment: Any news here? I need to ship 1.3 soon.

Comment: Apologies for the delay on my side, Viktor; I was away during the long weekend, unfortunately. Thanks for the pointer on the Akka build instructions and apologies for having missed that. I'm sending you an email right away. Will test the new versions as soon as I get them and let you know what I find. Will also set up the Akka build environment on my side for next time. Thanks again for all the help!