# How to exactly fix "You are creating too many HashedWheelTimer instances"?

Tags: multithreading, scala, playframework, netty

I have a Play application that creates a few `WSClient` since I have to limit the amount of maximum connections in each one (as they are used for different purposes and limits are different), and there's no global setting for this feature. I am getting this in the logs:

`ResourceLeakDetector - LEAK: You are creating too many HashedWheelTimer instances. HashedWheelTimer is a shared resource that must be reused across the JVM,so that only a few instances are created.`

I have tried to find a solution for this but unfortunately I have no idea how to share `HashedWheelTimer` instances between clients.

Comment: Are you closing the `WSClient`s after using them?

Comment: @marcospereira it's a Play application, so they get created on startup (as singleton) and injected into classes. They're not closed as they're constantly in use or with very short rest.

Comment: Have you seen this? 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8751801/akka-warning-about-too-many-hashedwheeltimer-instances